# Achieving real time preview in Sony Vegas Pro 11?

Tags: playback, preview

I am sort of blown away how I cannot even manage to achieve realtime preview in a **tiny** preview window size, at draft on auto.

The source footage is only 1080p. I have already tried Google search tips and tricks.

I have also tried enabling GPU acceleration of video processing, and reducing size of RAM reserved for Dynamic RAM Preview.

I have a fairly decent system, with a quad-core i5, 12GB Ram, and a GTX 560 Ti (1GB VRAM, 384 cores).

Yet, I still cannot get lag-free preview on DRAFT - QUARTER with a preview box of approx. 1-inch tall.

Premiere Pro CS6 doesn't seem to have any issues with the footage playback.

Comment: Nvidia driver version? OS?

Comment: I have the latest NVIDIA driver, 358.91. I am running Win7 Ultimate x64 SP1.